# How to make regular expression to filter out for specific words for url in php laravel 8?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-8

I want this regular expression to only show some specific pages under **cars** and **places** . With this regex I succeeded in filtering for just these two specific routes (cars, places). But further I want this to filter out some specific pages under each parent category i.e., cars, places.
example: under car I want to accept only specific words like : lambo, ferrari, markx, porche
which lets us accept:
`example.com/cars/lambo` **accept this** and if `example.com/cars/accord` **reject this url**

Like wise I want to accept some specific words only after **/places/** .

```
Route::get('/{exptrk}/{extrpage}', function($exptrk, $extrpage) {
    return $exptrk ;
})->where(['exptrk'=>'((\bcars\b))|((\bplaces\/\b))']);
```

I am using laraval8, Thanks

Comment: For a start you could just split them in two routes `Route::get('/cars/{extrpage}'..` `Route::get('/places/{extrpage}'..` and regex the parameters there

Comment: actually i wanted to have just one route,  tp handle both kinds of situations

Comment: So, you want `'(?:^|/)cars/(?:lambo|ferrari|markx|porche)(?:/|$)'`?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just make a controller class and point both routes to the same controller? That way they do the same and you don't have to mess with unreadable regex magic in your code.

So like:

```php
Route::get('/cars/{page}', CarsAndPlacesController::class);
Route::get('/places/{page}', CarsAndPlacesController::class);
```

With a controller like:

```php
class CarsAndPlacesController extends Controller {
    public function __invoke(string $page) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```